# Where is the "Publish" option in Visual Studio 2022 Mac

Tags: visual-studio-mac-2022

I recently set up Visual Studio 2022 (preview) on the Mac (M1) Version 17.3.
I spent quite a bit of time migrating an older .Net MVC (4.6.1) project and finally got it to build and run locally.

I them went to publish it to a test IIS server I run remotely but I cannot find the "Publish" option for the project. Any ideas? Thanks in advance. Hopefully a dumb question...

[image]